# MongoDВ поиск по сумме Date поля + TimeSpan поля

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

Нужна помощь с .Net драйвером для MongoDB.

Мой C# класс:

```
public class Document
 {
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }

    public TimeSpan CustomPeriod { get; set; }
 }
```

Нужно найти документы по StartTime + CustomPeriod как в этом предикате:

```
Expression<Func<Document, bool>> customExpression = x => x.StartTime.Add(x.CustomPeriod) <= DateTime.UtcNow;
```

Предикат сейчас не работает, при выполнении запроса Collection.Find() получаю ошибку:

> {document}{StartTime}.Add({document}{CustomPeriod}) is not supported.

Нужен способ найти документы по такому условию.

**UPD:**
Вот тут говорят, что сделать это нельзя, но прошло много времени, вдруг есть все же способ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25371537/using-mongodb-in-c-how-do-i-derive-a-timespan-from-a-value-in-a-record